# Problem with grpcio [process didn't exit successfully: "...\target\debug\build\grpcio-sys-9aa662d3a4136772\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)"]

Tags: rust, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpcio

I ran into a project build issue with the following output:

```
  error: failed to run custom build command for `grpcio-sys v0.12.1+1.46.5-patched`

  Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\..\target\debug\build\grpcio-sys-9aa662d3a4136772\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stderr
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

      CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS
      CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_DEBUG
      CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE


  CMake Warning at third_party/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:74 (message):
    A future Abseil release will default ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD to ON for CMake
    3.8 and up.  We recommend enabling this option to ensure your project still
    builds correctly.


  CMake Warning at cmake/protobuf.cmake:51 (message):
    gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER is "module" but PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR is wrong
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:317 (include)


  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

      CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS
      CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_DEBUG


  thread 'main' panicked at '
  command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

  build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\Mi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.49\src\lib.rs:1104:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

This happens when I try to build the project using:

```ini
[dependencies]
protobuf="3.2.0"
protobuf-codegen="3.2.0"
protocol-rust="2.28.0"
grpcio-compiler="0.12.1"
grpcio="0.12.1"
```

Without grpcio and/or grpcio-compiler i get error in the following code that compiler doesn't get grpcio's:

(code fragment of ptotobuf grpc file)

```rust
const METHOD_NODE_HANDSHAKE: ::grpcio::Method<super::messages::Version, super::messages::Version> = ::grpcio::Method {
    ty: ::grpcio::MethodType::Unary,
    name: "/messages.Node/Handshake",
    req_mar: ::grpcio::Marshaller { ser: ::grpcio::pb_ser, de: ::grpcio::pb_de },
    resp_mar: ::grpcio::Marshaller { ser: ::grpcio::pb_ser, de: ::grpcio::pb_de },
};

const METHOD_NODE_HANDLE_TRANSACTION: ::grpcio::Method<super::messages::Transaction, super::messages::Confirmed> = ::grpcio::Method {
    ty: ::grpcio::MethodType::Unary,
    name: "/messages.Node/HandleTransaction",
    req_mar: ::grpcio::Marshaller { ser: ::grpcio::pb_ser, de: ::grpcio::pb_de },
    resp_mar: ::grpcio::Marshaller { ser: ::grpcio::pb_ser, de: ::grpcio::pb_de },
};
```

I've already checked through versions of CMake, protoc ect.

So the question is what should I try?

Has anyone already encountered this problem?

Also I would like to ask about `PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR` environment variable. Because I've already set up my environment path var million times. Currently it has a value of Protobuf (C:/Program Files/Protobuf) which contains bin, include and readme, but compiler still says that `PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR` is wrong.

Comment: that's a lot of warnings/errors. it's not really good to ask one question to solve all of them.

Comment: @user, The main question is the failure of build script and this is the only error.
I provided whole output because it can contain usefull information for people that are able to solve this problem.
I don't need your criticism, but thank you.

Comment: I don't think a mark of a good [mre] involves several errors/warning from various dependencies.